# ¿Como arreglar los bucles infinitos entre otros fallos?

Tags: java

Bueno pues tal y como pone en el titulo este es mi programa que realiza combates del caballero del zodiacos creandolos y haciendo luchar heroes y villanos, mi problema es que al ejecutar la opcion numero 4 se queda en un bucle infinito, osea se no vuelve al menu para seleccionar otra opcion y no solo eso sino que ademas creo que tengo otros bucles infinitos y no los se ver en el programa ayuda porfavor

P.D: He borrado dos clases  ya que hay muchos caracteres y no me deja poner la pregunta igualmente creo que el problema esta en la principal

```
    import java.io.IOException;
    import java.util.ArrayList;
    import java.util.InputMismatchException;
    import java.util.Scanner;

    public class Principal {



                public static ArrayList<Caballeros> ListaCaballeros = new ArrayList<Caballeros>();
                public static ArrayList<Golpes> ListaGolpes = new ArrayList<Golpes>();
                public static ArrayList<Batalla> ListaBatallas = new ArrayList<Batalla>();


            public static void main(String[] args) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                 Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

                int opcion;
                int numpersonaje = 0;
                int contadortecnicas = 0;
                int numbatallas = 0;


                    do {
                        System.out.println("Elija la opción más adecuada*"
                                + "\n"                     
                                + "\n1.  Listar Caballeros y Golpes *"
                                + "\n2.  Listar las Batallas "
                                + "\n3.  Crear un nuevo Caballero o Villano"
                                + "\n4.  Eliminar un Caballero o Villano"
                                + "\n5.  Lucha*"
                                + "\n6.  Salir ");

                        opcion = sc.nextInt();
                        switch (opcion){
                        case 1:
                            listarCaballeros(ListaCaballeros, ListaGolpes);
                            if (numpersonaje == 0){
                                System.out.println(" Aún no existe ningún caballero,  \n");
                            }
                            break;
                        case 2:
                            if(numbatallas>0) {
                                listarBatallas(ListaBatallas);
                            }
                            else {
                                System.out.println("NO EXISTE NINGUNA BATALLA");

                            }
                            break;
                        case 3:
                            crearCaballeros(ListaCaballeros,ListaGolpes);
                            contadortecnicas=ListaGolpes.size();
                            numpersonaje=ListaCaballeros.size();

                            break;
                        case 4:
                            eliminarCaballeros(ListaCaballeros);
                            break;
                        case 5:
                            lucharCaballeros(ListaCaballeros, ListaGolpes, ListaBatallas, numbatallas, numpersonaje);
                            numbatallas=ListaBatallas.size();
                            break;

                        case 6:
                            System.out.println("");
                            System.out.println("Adios ***");
                            break;
                        }
                    } while (opcion != 6);

            }

            public static void crearCaballeros(ArrayList<Caballeros> ListaCaballeros,ArrayList<Golpes> ListaGolpes){

                System.out.println("Crear un caballero");
                Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

                    System.out.println("Nombre: ");
                    String nombre = sc.next();
                    System.out.println("Constelacion: ");
                    String constelacion = sc.next();
                    System.out.println("Edad: ");
                    int edad =0;
                  boolean success = false;
                    while(success == false) {
                        try {
                            edad = sc.nextInt();
                            if(edad >0){
                            success = true;
                            }else{
                                System.out.println("FALLO pon número válido");
                            }
                        } catch (Exception e) {
                            sc.next(); 
                            System.out.println("FALLO pon número válido");
                        }


                    System.out.println("Altura: mide en metros");
                    int altura = 0;
                    boolean success2 = false;
                    while(success2 == false) {
                        try {
                            altura = sc.nextInt();
                            if(altura >0){
                            success2 = true;
                            }else{
                                System.out.println("Otra vez");
                            }
                        } catch (Exception e) {
                            sc.next(); 
                            System.out.println("Otra vez");
                        }
                    }


                    System.out.println("Peso: ");
                    int peso = 0;
                    boolean success3 = false;
                    while(success3 == false) {
                        try {
                            peso = sc.nextInt();
                            if(peso >0){
                            success3 = true;
                            }else{
                                System.out.println("otra vez ");
                            }
                        } catch (Exception e) {
                            sc.next();
                            System.out.println("Otra vez");
                        }
                    }

                    System.out.println("Nacimiento: ");
                    String nacimiento = sc.next();
                    System.out.println("Lugar de origen: ");
                    String lugar_de_origen = sc.next();
                    System.out.println("Lugar de entrenamiento: ");
                    String lugar_de_entrenamiento = sc.next();
                    System.out.println("Categoria: ");
                    String categoria = sc.next();
                    System.out.println("Vida: ");
                    int vida = 0;
                    boolean success5 = false;
                    while(success5 == false) {
                        try {
                            vida = sc.nextInt();
                            if(vida >0){
                            success5 = true;
                            }else{
                                System.out.println("POR FAVOR VUELVE A INTENTARLO");
                            }
                        } catch (Exception e) {
                            sc.next(); 
                            System.out.println("POR FAVOR VUELVE A INTENTARLO");
                        }
                    }

                    System.out.println("Es Villano?: ");

                    String input = "";
                boolean villano = true;
                boolean cpr = true;
                while (cpr == true){
                    input = sc.next();
                    if (input.toLowerCase().equals("no")||input.toLowerCase().equals("nop") ||input.toLowerCase().equals("false")){
                        villano  = false;
                        cpr = false;
                    } else if (input.toLowerCase().equals("si") ||input.toLowerCase().equals("sip") ||input.toLowerCase().equals("true")){
                        villano = true;
                        cpr = false;
                    } else {
                        System.out.println("POR FAVOR VUELVE A INTENTARLO (Si o no / true o false)");
                    }
                }
                    System.out.println("Tecnica:");
                    System.out.println("");
                    System.out.println("Nombre tecnica:");
                    String nombretecnica=sc.next();
                    System.out.println("Fuerza:");
                    int fuerza = 0;

                    boolean success6 = false;
                    while(success6 == false) {
                        try {
                            fuerza = sc.nextInt();
                            if(fuerza>0){
                            success6 = true;
                            }else{
                                System.out.println("Introduce un número válido ");
                            }
                        } catch (Exception e) {
                            sc.next(); 
                            System.out.println("Introduce un número válido ");
                        }
                    }
                    System.out.println("Descripcion:");
                    String descripcion = sc.next();

                    Golpes g1 = new Golpes(nombretecnica, fuerza, descripcion);
                    ListaGolpes.add(g1);
                     System.out.println("Tecnica2:");
                        System.out.println("");
                        System.out.println("Nombre tecnica2:");
                        String nombretecnica2=sc.next();
                        System.out.println("Fuerza2:");
                        int fuerza2 =0;

                        boolean success11 = false;
                        while(success11 == false) {
                            try {
                                fuerza2 = sc.nextInt();
                                if(fuerza2>0){
                                success11 = true;
                                }else{
                                    System.out.println("Introduce un número válido (Mayor que 0)!!");
                                }
                            } catch (Exception e) {
                                sc.next(); 
                                System.out.println("Introduce un número válido (Mayor que 0)!!");
                            }
                        }

                        System.out.println("Descripcion2:");
                        String descripcion2 = sc.next();

                    Golpes g2 = new Golpes(nombretecnica2, fuerza2, descripcion2);
                    ListaGolpes.add(g2);
                     System.out.println("Tecnica3:");
                        System.out.println("");
                        System.out.println("Nombre tecnica3:");
                        String nombretecnica3=sc.next();
                        System.out.println("Fuerza3:");
                        int fuerza3 = 0;
                        boolean success22 = false;
                        while(success22 == false) {
                            try {
                                fuerza3 = sc.nextInt();
                                if(fuerza3>0){
                                success22 = true;
                                }else{
                                    System.out.println("Introduce un número válido (Mayor que 0)!!");
                                }
                            } catch (Exception e) {
                                sc.next(); 
                                System.out.println("Introduce un número válido (Mayor que 0)!!");
                            }
                        }
                        System.out.println("Descripcion3:");
                        String descripcion3 = sc.next();

                    Golpes g3 = new Golpes(nombretecnica3, fuerza3, descripcion3);

                    ListaGolpes.add(g3);

                    Caballeros C = new Caballeros(nombre,constelacion,edad,altura,peso,nacimiento,lugar_de_origen,lugar_de_entrenamiento,categoria,vida,villano,ListaGolpes);

                    ListaCaballeros.add(C);
                    System.out.println("");
                    System.out.println("oleee, uno más, espero que siga creando más");
                    System.out.println("");
                    }
            }


            public static void listarCaballeros(ArrayList<Caballeros>ListaCaballeros,ArrayList<Golpes>ListaGolpes){

                int indice=0;

                for(int i=0;i<ListaCaballeros.size();i++){

                    System.out.println("Nombre: " + ListaCaballeros.get(i).getNombre());
                    System.out.println("Constelacion: " + ListaCaballeros.get(i).getConstelacion() );
                    System.out.println("Edad: " + ListaCaballeros.get(i).getEdad());
                    System.out.println("Altura: " + ListaCaballeros.get(i).getAltura());
                    System.out.println("Peso: " + ListaCaballeros.get(i).getPeso());
                    System.out.println("Nacimiento: " + ListaCaballeros.get(i).getNacimiento());
                    System.out.println("Lugar de origen: " + ListaCaballeros.get(i).getLugar_de_origen());
                    System.out.println("Lugar de entrenamiento: " + ListaCaballeros.get(i).getLugar_de_entrenamiento());
                    System.out.println("Categoria: " + ListaCaballeros.get(i).getCategoría());
                    System.out.println("Vida: " + ListaCaballeros.get(i).getVida());
                    System.out.println("Villano: " + ListaCaballeros.get(i).getVillano());



                    for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
                        System.out.print("Técnica: " + "Nombre:" + ListaCaballeros.get(i).getTecnica().get(indice).getNombre() + ", Fuerza: "  +
                        ListaCaballeros.get(i).getTecnica().get(indice).getFuerza() + ", Descripcion: " +  
                        ListaCaballeros.get(i).getTecnica().get(indice).getDescripcion() + "\n");
                        indice++;
                        }

                        System.out.println();
                }

                }


            public static void eliminarCaballeros(ArrayList<Caballeros> caballero){
                Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
                try {
                    System.out.println("Escribe a continuación el nombre del personaje que quieres borrar:");
                    String nombre = sc.nextLine();
                    for(Caballeros c : caballero) {
                        if(nombre.equals(c.getNombre())) {
                            caballero.remove(caballero.lastIndexOf(c));
                            System.out.println("Eliminado con éxito");
                        }
                    }
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    sc.next(); 
                    System.out.println("Introduce un nombre sin FALLO");
                }
            }


            public static void listarBatallas(ArrayList<Batalla> listaBatallas){

                System.out.println("Lista de batallas");

                for(int i=0;i<listaBatallas.size();i++){


                    System.out.println("Batalla numero:"+i+1);
                    System.out.println("Nombre atacante:"+listaBatallas.get(i).getAtacante().getNombre());
                    System.out.println("Nombre atacado:"+listaBatallas.get(i).getAtacado().getNombre());
                    System.out.println("Numero de Turno:"+listaBatallas.get(i).getTurno());         
                    System.out.println("Numero de ataques totales:"+listaBatallas.get(i).getNum_ataques());
                    System.out.println("ganador:"+listaBatallas.get(i).getGanador());
                }


            }

            public static void lucharCaballeros(ArrayList<Caballeros> lcaballeros, ArrayList<Golpes> ltec, ArrayList<Batalla> listaB, int numbat, int numpersonaje){



            if (numpersonaje >= 2){

                    int contadorturno=0;

                    int numataques=0;

                    String ganador;

                    Scanner sc1= new Scanner(System.in);
                    Scanner sc2= new Scanner(System.in);

                    System.out.print(" ¿Quien lucha? \n Sólo  luchan los héroes contra los villanos \n\n ");
                    int numtec = 0;
                    for (int i = 0; i < lcaballeros.size(); i++) {
                        System.out.print("Caballero número :  " + (i + 1)  + "  \n");
                        System.out.print(" "+ lcaballeros.get(i).getNombre().toUpperCase() + " \n");

                        if(lcaballeros.get(i).getVillano()== true){
                            System.out.print("  VILLANO  \n");
                        } else {
                            System.out.print("  HÉROE\n");
                        }   



            System.out.println(" Vida: "+ lcaballeros.get(i).getVida()+ " \n");
                int num = 1;

                for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
                System.out.print("Técnica " + num + " : " + lcaballeros.get(i).getTecnica().get(numtec).getNombre() + ", "  +

                lcaballeros.get(i).getTecnica().get(numtec).getFuerza() + ", " +  
                lcaballeros.get(i).getTecnica().get(numtec).getDescripcion() + "\n");
                    numtec++;
                    num++;
        }

                System.out.println();
        }   



                System.out.println(" Selecciona el número o nombre del primer caballero: ");


                    int input = 0;
                    while (input == 0){
                        String inputS = sc1.next();
                    try{
                        if (Integer.valueOf(inputS) > 0 && Integer.parseInt(inputS)<= lcaballeros.size()){
                        input = Integer.parseInt(inputS);
                            } 
                        }catch (Exception e){}

                        for(int i = 0 ; i<lcaballeros.size();i++){
                            if (inputS.toUpperCase().equals(lcaballeros.get(i).getNombre().toUpperCase())){
                                input = i+1;
                            }
                        } if(input == 0){
                            System.out.println(" Fallo-- \n\n -- Vuelva a intentarlo");

                        }
                    }


            int numtec1 = ((input)*3) - 1;

                System.out.print("numeero  " + (input)  + " seleccionado \n\n");
                System.out.print(" "+ lcaballeros.get(input-1).getNombre().toUpperCase() + "  \n");




                if(lcaballeros.get(input-1).getVillano()== true){
                    System.out.print("  VILLANO \n");
                } else {
                    System.out.print(" HÉROE  \n");
                }


                System.out.println("- Puntos de salud: "+ lcaballeros.get(input-1).getVida()+ " \n");
                int num = 1;




                for (int j = numtec1 -2; j < ((input)*3); j++) {
                    System.out.print("Técnica " + num + " : " + lcaballeros.get(input-1).getTecnica().get(j).getNombre() + ", "  +
                            lcaballeros.get(input-1).getTecnica().get(j).getFuerza() + ", " +  
                            lcaballeros.get(input-1).getTecnica().get(j).getDescripcion() + "\n");
                    num++;
                }   

                System.out.println();



                System.out.println(" -- Selecciona el número o nombre del segundo caballero: ");


                int input2 = 0;
                boolean comprob = false;
                int salida = 0;
                while (comprob == false){
                    String inputS = sc2.next();

    try{
                    if (Integer.valueOf(inputS) > 0 && Integer.parseInt(inputS)<= lcaballeros.size()){
                    input2 = Integer.parseInt(inputS);
                    if(lcaballeros.get(input-1).getVillano()!= lcaballeros.get(input2-1).getVillano()){
                    comprob = true;
                            }
                    if((lcaballeros.get(input-1).getVillano()== lcaballeros.get(input2-1).getVillano()) && 
                            (input2 > 0 && input2 <= lcaballeros.size())){
                    System.out.println("Fallo\n\n"
                            + "Los jugadores dispuestos a luchar no pueden ser ambos villanos o héroes \n"
                            + "\n Seleccione otro caballero: \n\n(Si no tiene un villano o héroe adecuado");
                            }
                        } 
                    }

                    catch (Exception e){}


                    for(int i = 0 ; i<lcaballeros.size();i++){
                        if (inputS.toUpperCase().equals(lcaballeros.get(i).getNombre().toUpperCase())){
                            input2 = i+1;
                            if(lcaballeros.get(input-1).getVillano()== lcaballeros.get(input2-1).getVillano()){
                                System.out.println("FALLORRRR\n\n"
                                        + "Los caballeros no pueden ser ambos villanos o héroes");
                                    } 
                            if(lcaballeros.get(input-1).getVillano()!= lcaballeros.get(input2-1).getVillano()){
                            comprob = true;
                            }
                        }
                    } 



                    if(input2 == 0){
                        System.out.println(); 
                        System.out.println(" ERROOOOOOOR \n\n  Vuelva a introducirlolololo los datos correctamente--");
                    }
                    if (inputS.toLowerCase().equals("salir")){
                        salida++;
                        comprob = true;
                    } 
                }
                if (salida == 1){
                    return;
                }


                int numtec2 = ((input2)*3) - 1;
                System.out.print("Caballero número :  " + (input2)  + " seleccionado \n\n");
                System.out.print("  "+ lcaballeros.get(input2-1).getNombre().toUpperCase() + "  \n");


                if(lcaballeros.get(input2-1).getVillano()== true){
                    System.out.print("villano");
                } else {
                    System.out.print("heroe");
                }
                System.out.println("Vida: "+ lcaballeros.get(input2-1).getVida()+ " \n");

                num = 1;


                for (int j = numtec2 -2; j < ((input2)*3); j++) {
                    System.out.print("Técnica " + num + " : " + lcaballeros.get(input2-1).getTecnica().get(j).getNombre() + ", "  +
                            lcaballeros.get(input2-1).getTecnica().get(j).getFuerza() + ", " +  
                            lcaballeros.get(input2-1).getTecnica().get(j).getDescripcion() + "\n");
                    num++;
                }
                    System.out.println();



                System.out.println(" MORTAL KOMBATTTTTT START \n");





                while (lcaballeros.get(input-1).getVida()> 0 ||  lcaballeros.get(input2-1).getVida()> 0){

                    System.out.println("Primer caballero, es tu turno: \n\n");
                    System.out.print("  "+ lcaballeros.get(input-1).getNombre().toUpperCase() + "  \n");

                    if(lcaballeros.get(input-1).getVillano()== true){
                        System.out.print("                      - VILLANO -               \n");
                    } else {
                        System.out.print("                      - HÉROE -                 8\n");
                    }
                    System.out.println("Vida: "+ lcaballeros.get(input-1).getVida()+ " \n");

                    num = 1;

                    for (int j = numtec1 -2; j < ((input)*3); j++) {
                        System.out.print("Técnica " + num + " : " + lcaballeros.get(input-1).getTecnica().get(j).getNombre() + ", "  +
                                lcaballeros.get(input-1).getTecnica().get(j).getFuerza() + ", " +  
                                lcaballeros.get(input-1).getTecnica().get(j).getDescripcion() + "\n");
                        num++;
                    }

                    System.out.println();
                    contadorturno++;

                    System.out.println("Seleccione que golpe quiere darle ");
                     int intec;




                     while(true){


                            try {
                                intec = sc1.nextInt();
                                while(intec < 1 || intec >3){
                                    System.out.println("El número introducido no es correcto! Vuelva a introducirlo \n");
                                    intec = sc1.nextInt();
                                }
                                break; 
                            } catch(InputMismatchException e){
                                sc1.next(); 
                                System.out.println( "El número introducido no es correcto! Vuelva a introducirlo\n");
                            }
                        }



                        int tec = intec + ((input*3)-3);

                    lcaballeros.get(input-1).getTecnica().get(tec-1).getFuerza();


                    System.out.println(lcaballeros.get(input-1).getNombre().toUpperCase() + " realiza el ataque : " + 
                            lcaballeros.get(input-1).getTecnica().get(tec-1).getNombre() + " !");


                    numataques++;

                    System.out.println(" El caballero "+ lcaballeros.get(input2-1).getNombre().toUpperCase() + " pierde "
                            + lcaballeros.get(input-1).getTecnica().get(tec-1).getFuerza() + " puntos de vida! \n\n");
                    lcaballeros.get(input2-1).setVida(lcaballeros.get(input2-1).getVida() - lcaballeros.get(input-1).getTecnica().get(tec-1).getFuerza());


                    if (lcaballeros.get(input2-1).getVida() > 0){
                        System.out.println(" El caballero " + lcaballeros.get(input2-1).getNombre().toUpperCase() + " tiene " + lcaballeros.get(input2-1).getVida()
                            + " puntos de vida restantes!");
                    } else {
                        System.out.println(" El caballero " + lcaballeros.get(input2-1).getNombre().toUpperCase()
                                + " ha perdido ");
                        lcaballeros.get(input2-1).setVida(lcaballeros.get(input2-1).getVida() + 50);

                         ganador=" El caballero " + lcaballeros.get(input-1).getNombre().toUpperCase()
                                    + " ha ganado !";


                        lcaballeros.get(input-1).setVida(lcaballeros.get(input-1).getVida() + 50);
                        System.out.println(" El caballero " + lcaballeros.get(input-1).getNombre().toUpperCase()
                                + " aumenta su salud en 50 pts! Puntos de salud actuales: " + lcaballeros.get(input-1).getVida() +"\n\n");





                        Batalla b1 = new Batalla(lcaballeros.get(input-1),lcaballeros.get(input2-1),contadorturno,numataques,ganador);


                        listaB.add(b1);
                        for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
                            ltec.remove(numtec2);
                            numtec2--;
                            }
                        lcaballeros.remove(input2 -1);
                        break;
                        }


                        System.out.println("Turno del segundo caballero: \n\n");
                        System.out.print("  "+ lcaballeros.get(input2-1).getNombre().toUpperCase() + "  \n");

                        if(lcaballeros.get(input2-1).getVillano()== true){
                            System.out.print(" VILLANO  \n");
                        } else {
                            System.out.print(" HÉROE  \n");
                        }

                        System.out.println("Vida: "+lcaballeros.get(input2-1).getVida()+ " \n");

                        num = 1;

                        for (int j = numtec2 -2; j < ((input2)*3); j++) {
                            System.out.print("Técnica " + num + " : " + lcaballeros.get(input-1).getTecnica().get(j).getNombre() + ", "  +
                            lcaballeros.get(input2-1).getTecnica().get(j).getFuerza() + ", " +  
                            lcaballeros.get(input2-1).getTecnica().get(j).getDescripcion() + "\n");
                            num++;
                        }

                        System.out.println();

                        System.out.println("Seleccione que técnica quiere utilizar. (1, 2, 3)");
                        int intec2 = 0;

                        while(true){

                            try {
                                intec2 = sc2.nextInt();
                                while(intec2 < 1 || intec2 >3){
                                    System.out.println("El número introducido no es correcto! Vuelva a introducirlolololo  \n");
                                    intec2 = sc1.nextInt();
                                }
                                break;
                            } catch(InputMismatchException e){
                                sc2.next(); 
                                System.out.println( "El número introducido no es correcto! Vuelva a introducirlolololo un número \n");
                            }
                        }

                        int tec2 = intec2 + ((input2*3)-3);

                        lcaballeros.get(input2-1).getTecnica().get(tec2-1).getFuerza();

                        System.out.println(lcaballeros.get(input2-1).getNombre().toUpperCase() + " realiza el ataque : " + 
                        lcaballeros.get(input2-1).getTecnica().get(tec2-1).getNombre() + " !");

                        numataques++;


                        System.out.println(" El caballero "+ lcaballeros.get(input-1).getNombre().toUpperCase() + " pierde "
                        + lcaballeros.get(input2-1).getTecnica().get(tec2-1).getFuerza() + " puntos vida! \n\n");
                        lcaballeros.get(input-1).setVida(lcaballeros.get(input-1).getVida() - lcaballeros.get(input2-1).getTecnica().get(tec2-1).getFuerza());



                        if (lcaballeros.get(input-1).getVida() > 0){
                            System.out.println(" El caballero " + lcaballeros.get(input-1).getNombre().toUpperCase() + " tiene " + lcaballeros.get(input-1).getVida()
                                + " puntos de salud restantes!");
                        } else {
                            System.out.println(" El caballero " + lcaballeros.get(input-1).getNombre().toUpperCase()
                                    + " ha perdido ");

                             ganador=" El caballero " + lcaballeros.get(input2-1).getNombre().toUpperCase()
                                        + " ha ganado ";

                            lcaballeros.get(input2-1).setVida(lcaballeros.get(input2-1).getVida() + 50);
                            System.out.println(" El caballero " + lcaballeros.get(input2-1).getNombre().toUpperCase()
                                    + " aumenta su vida 50 pts! Vida actual: " + lcaballeros.get(input2-1).getVida()+"\n\n");


                            Batalla b2 = new Batalla(lcaballeros.get(input-1),lcaballeros.get(input2-1),contadorturno,numataques,ganador);
                            listaB.add(b2);

                            for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
                                ltec.remove(numtec1);
                                numtec1--;
                                }

                            lcaballeros.remove(input -1);

                            break;
                            }

                        }
                    } else if (numpersonaje < 2){
                        System.out.println("El número de personajes debe de ser 2 o mas para luchar.\n");
                    }   
                }


            }
```

Comment: Hola, te damos la bienvenida al sitio. Completa el [tour] y lee sobre cómo crear un [mcve]. Es importante identificar las partes de código concretas porque eso facilita a otros usuarios a encontrar la raíz del problema.

Comment: Tu pregunta es muy amplia, céntrate en el bucle infinito o cada uno de los otros fallos

Answer (score 3):

```
for(Caballeros c : caballero) {
    if(nombre.equals(c.getNombre())) {
        caballero.remove(caballero.lastIndexOf(c)); // <<--- modificas la lista!!!
        System.out.println("Eliminado con éxito");
    }
}
```

No debes modificar la lista mientras estás iterándola con un for basado en rangos porque entonces puedes tener comportamientos como el que estás experimentando

En vez de un for basado en rangos, puedes optar por usar iteradores:

```
Iterator itr = caballero.iterator(); 
while( itr.hasNext() )
{ 
    Caballero c = (Caballero)itr.next(); 
    if( nombre.equals(caballero.nombre) ) 
        itr.remove(); 
}
```